# Ckeck the presence of xml tag using oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, clob

```
 <wbi:appData>
     <wbi:content wbi:name="1st_status">
         <wbi:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Success</wbi:value>
     </wbi:content>
</wbi:appData>
```

this xml is in a table which has a column in the form of CLOB type.

I wanted to find if "wbi:value" tag exists in this xml or not ?

I tried using existsnode but in sql developer it is saying an error as to declare existsnode.

Comment: It would be best if you post your actual code. You asked how to detect a particular node in SQL, which everyone has answered. This is why it's always best to show your past effort and research. If you post your trigger code and the error  messages you're getting with what you're doing then maybe people would be able to help better?

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER Tab_a`
`BEFORE INSERT`
`FOR EACH ROW`
`declare`
  `xml_a xmltype;`
   `begin`
    `xml_a:=xmltype(:new.value);`

`--here i have to check if "wbi:value" exists in the xml clob and `
 `then`

     `----insert function`

    `end;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes use existsnode:

```
SQL> with yourdata as (select to_clob('<wbi:event xmlns:wbi="http://foo" xmlns:xsi="http://x" xmlns:xsd="http://d">
  2  <wbi:appData>
  3      <wbi:content wbi:name="1st_status">
  4          <wbi:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Success</wbi:value>
  5          </wbi:content>
  6      <wbi:content wbi:name="2nd_status">
  7          <wbi:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Failure</wbi:value>
  8          </wbi:content>
  9      </wbi:appData>
 10  </wbi:event>') c from dual)
 11  select existsnode(xmltype(c), '/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"')  is_exist
 12    from yourdata t
 13  /

  IS_EXIST
----------
         1
```

ie

```
existsnode(xmltype(c), '/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"')
```

1 = exists
0 = does not exist.

note that in my sample, i had two matching nodes (as i didn't filter on wbi:name). you can filter the xpath of course. eg:

```
/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content[@wbi:name="1st_status"]
```

to limit matches to the "1st_status" one

Comment: Thanks :) but when i am using it in a trigger with table name "yourdata" and if i mention "yourdata" again in select statement it shows error.  Can the same table name be used in how many ever select statement inside the trigger having both table name inside select statemt and trigger table being same ?

Comment: the yourdata with part was just my sample. if you mean that the trigger is on the table with the clob column, just reference the clob column as `v_exists := xmltype(:new.clobcolumn).existsNode('xpath', 'namespace');` please paste your trigger code for a more complete response.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER Tab_a`
`BEFORE INSERT`
`FOR EACH ROW`
`declare`
  `xml_a xmltype;`
   `begin`
    `xml_a:=xmltype(:new.value);`

`--here i have to check if "wbi:value" exists in the xml clob and `
 `then`

     `----insert function`

    `end;`

Comment: Ok so if(xml_a.existsNode('/wbi:event/wbi:appData/wbi:content','xmlns:wbi="http://foo"') =1) then

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) 
 from clobtab
where existsNode(xmltype.createxml(clobcol),'/wbi:appData/wbi:content/wbi:value') = 1;
```

If it reurns more than 0 then it exists otherwise not.

So your trigger would be-

```
CREATE TRIGGER Tab_a 
BEFORE INSERT 
FOR EACH ROW 
declare 
   xml_a xmltype; 
begin 
   xml_a:=xmltype(:new.value); 
   if existsNode(xml_a,'/wbi:appData/wbi:content/wbi:value','xmlns:wbi="http://pat.namespace.com"') = 1
   then 
     ----insert .... 
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanku but it s not helping :( It says existsNode is not declared ...
I am trying to do the above inside a trigger.

Comment: `existsNode()` should work perfectly fine in 10g. What version is your DB?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can use oracle's instr function, which is fast.

like:

```
where instr(field, 'wbi:value') > 0
```

Comment: If the string 'wbi:value' occurs somewhere not as a tag, this would match as well.

Comment: Who on earth would want to write "wbi:value" not in tags? anyway, this code isn't final, so it is possible to write '<wbi:value'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLEXISTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions231.htm#SQLRF20013):

```
SELECT DESCRIPTOR_XML FROM TABLE_WITH_AN_XMLTYPE_COLUMN
WHERE
  XMLEXISTS('//functions[function/arg[@name="class.name" and not(starts-with(., "com.example.apps.YouShantSeeMeClass"))]]'
  PASSING BY VALUE DESCRIPTOR_XML);
```